# Why entered key word is not store in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I had made on form, in which i had one text area. 
Now i am storing that data of text area to mysql database.
Now if i had press enter key word then it not stores in the database.
Because i don't get exacted output as what i entered.

as example...

If i had write like this.....

Good
Morning
How are you?

then i only get like this...

Good Morning How are you?

So its not storing that enter key word in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the textarea content with [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) then store it.

It will convert your newlines to `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are outputting HTML which doesn't render line breaks. Try using [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the \n character is stored in the database. However it wont be rendered if you display the output on a web page. Just replace \n with `<br >`

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying your stored text as HTML then `\n` are getting ignored. PHP has [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function that would convert linebreaks to `<br>`, just run your text through it before displaying.