# Preserving newlines entered into a textarea

Tags: php, html, database, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why entered key word is not store in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816262/why-entered-key-word-is-not-store-in-database)

I'm writing a simple page in which users can enter a testimonial about the website into a textarea box. This gets stored in my database inside a table called testimonials under "testimonial" which is of type text(1000)

When I try to retrieve the testimonials and present them and an unordered list, newlines get ignored.

For example:

I hate this website.

It has tons of bugs.

Will print as

- I hate this website. It has tons of bugs

How would one preserve the newline the user entered?

EDIT: I should mention that the testimonial is stored correctly with newlines in the database, when I look at it in phyMyAdmin

Comment: You need to convert the newline into a <br> character - it's still there, but not displayed. I think `nl2br()` is what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a browser will not render `\n` you need to use a function called [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to replace new lines with `<br/>`

Answer (score 1):

Call `nl2br()` right after you had called `htmlspecialchars()` with your content.

E.g. it should be like this:

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content));
```

Another solution would be to format the content with CSS that it preserves whitespace, like inside `<pre>` tags.