# How to display the format of the content from the database same as it was entered by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css, jsp

I'm sorry if the title sounds confusing but I don't know how to express the problem in one line. Anyway here are the details,

I have a `textarea` in which the user input data and then I store the data in my MySQL 5.5 database. The user inputs the data in well formated form i.e. leaving lines using `'enter key'`.

Eg:

text text text text

text text text

text text text text text text

Now when I retrieve the data from the database it is not displayed in the form as it was entered by the user but as follows,

Eg:

text text text text text text text text text text text text text

Is there a way through which I can make the format of the text same as it was entered by the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why entered key word is not store in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816262/why-entered-key-word-is-not-store-in-database)

Comment: please share your html code or jsfiddle.

Comment: @mhasan the link you gave is for PHP, can you provide me anything for JSP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing TextArea data with line breaks in database and displaying in same format with line breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062358/storing-textarea-data-with-line-breaks-in-database-and-displaying-in-same-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you insert the data from textarea new line will be marked as `\n` so when you retrieve it and display it in textarea it will display the same as you entered.

But if you want to display it on the html. you will see the plan text without new line because html cannot understand the `\n` so replace `\n` with html new line tag `<br/>`

```
$string = "something \n here";
echo str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $string);
```

Comment: I tried your code but know I'm getting the display as 'text text <br> text text text <br> text <br>'

Comment: Got it, I was using <c:out value='${userInput}'/> but when I used ${userInput} everything worked fine.